# Login user via Twitter or LinkedIn OAuth without opening a popup

Tags: php, api, twitter, linkedin-api

I've implemented login with Twitter via their OAuth API. I've decided to use a popup for Authorization/Authentication, which closes itself when the process ends.

However, it really bugs me that once a user has already **Authorized** my app, and he is also **Authenticated** with Twitter, the popup will simply open and close itself. I'd like to avoid creating the popup completely, but the other option is to redirect the main page for Authentication, which again I'd like to avoid since it has a flicker effect going to Twitter and back to my site.

What I'm asking, is it possible to Authenticate the user with Twitter via AJAX or any another option which doesn't require a pointless open-close popup, or flickering the screen back-and-forth with Twitter?

Facebook does this via their JS API with Ajax, but I'm asking for a server-to-server solution (I think Twitter forbids OAuth from the client anyway).

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the token you don't need to reauthenticate the user.

Comment: @Eragonio you're correct, but I have to assume the user just fired up his browser and opened my page. He's already been on my page before, has authorized the app and is already logged in with Twitter, however, I have no clues as to who he is until I get a note from Twitter. Is there a way of getting that note in async mode - without a browser window actually visiting the Twitter endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

For LinkedIn, if you are using the REST API, you can [send users to the authenticate endpoint](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/oauth-now-authentication):

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authenticate
```

If they are still logged in and their OAuth token is still valid, they will not see anything.

Comment: Actually, for LinkedIn I can use their JS API which is able to login the user in async mode. If using the REST API I have the same problem as I do with Twitter, which is: I need to send the user to LinkedIn so he can Authenticate or be redirected back is he's already Authenticated. This forces me to either load an empty popup that will show for a split second and close itself, or redirect the entire page to LinkedIn and be redirected back immediately. Both options suck in terms of presentation for the user.